# Square in Interval of Primes

Tags: prime-numbers

Denote by $a_n$ the sum of the first $n$ primes. Prove that there is a perfect square between $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$, inclusive, for all $n$.

The first few sums of primes are $2$, $5$, $10$, $17$, $28$, $41$, $58$, $75$. It seems there is a perfect square between each pair of successive sums. In addition, we can put a bound on $a_n$, namely $a_n \le 2+3+5+7+9+11+...+(2n+1)=n^2+2n+5$.

Comment: Please include what you've attempted or have trouble with. As it is, it's not a question but a command.

Comment: "The first few primes are $2, 5, 10,\ldots$"; I don't agree.

Comment: @daniel: I've edited, and at the same time corrected a few other errors (sense of the inequality, and evaluation of the sum).

Comment: [See also this.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763223)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Existence of perfect square between the sum of the first $n$ and $n + 1$ prime numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763223/existence-of-perfect-square-between-the-sum-of-the-first-n-and-n-1-prime-n)

Comment: The last element in the sample sequence 2,5,10,... should be 77 not 75.

Comment: By the way, this problem was on one of the national olympiads and was on one of our problem sets called _Recurrences in Combinatorics Part 1_

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the $(n+1)$st prime. Then $a_n\le (-8)+(1+3+5+7+9+\ldots +p-2)=(\frac{p-1}{2})^2-8$ provided $p\ge 11$ (the smaller cases can be dealt with by checking manually). So with $b_n:=\lfloor \sqrt {a_n}\rfloor $ we have $b_n< \frac{p-1}{2}$. Then $a_n<(b_n+1)^2=b_n^2+2b_n+1< a_n+p=a_{n+1}$ as was to be shown.

Comment: I think I can see where you are going, but you forgot to pronounce any of the arguments you are using, leaving just the formulas. For instance I would guess you are bounding the sum of prime numbers up to $p$ by the sum of all odd numbers up to $p$, but the appearance of $-8$ is a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

(waving my hands frantically to keep me aloft:)

$a_n
\approx \sum_{k=1}^n k\ln k
\approx \int_{1}^n k \ln k\ dk
\approx n^2\ln n
$
and
$a_{n+1}-a_n
\approx n\ln n
$
so if
$b_n
= \lfloor \sqrt{a_n}\rfloor
$,
$b_n
\approx n\sqrt{\ln n}
$.

The next square
after $b_n^2$
is 
$(b_n+1)^2
=b_n^2+2b_n+1
\approx b_n^2+2n\sqrt{\ln n}
$
and since
$a_{n+1}-a_n
\approx n\ln n
$,
$(b_n+1)^2
< a_{n+1}
$
for large anough $n$.

Note that
$(b_n+k)^2
=b_n^2+2kb_n+k^2
\approx b_n^2+2kn\sqrt{\ln n}
$,
so,
by choosing
$k \approx \frac12 \sqrt{\ln n}$, 
it looks like
there are about
$\frac12 \sqrt{\ln n}$
squares between
$a_n$ and
$a_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

This result follows from the well established fact that all primes numbers, with the exception of the first one which is$~2$, are odd.

Observe that for any positive integer$~n$, (a) the sum of all positive odd numbers less than $2n$ is $n^2$, and (b) the first gap of $2n$ successive natural numbers containing no perfect square is the range $n^2+1,\ldots,n^2+2n$.

I prove a stronger statement: for any set $S$ of positive odd numbers that includes $1$, if $2n-1$ is its greatest element, there is a perfect square among the $2n$ numbers $a-(2n-1),\ldots,a$ where $a=1+\sum S$.

(Apply this to the sequence of prime numbers after subtracting $1$ from the initial prime number $2$, which subtraction is compensated by the additional term $1$ in the expression for $a$.)

By the above observation (b) it suffices to show that $a-(2n-1)\leq n^2$, and since $n\geq1$ follows from $\sum S\leq n^2$ obtained from observation (a) (the sum of a subset of positive numbers is at most the sum of all).